# Java, how to find out if printerjob has finished

Tags: java, printing, pdfbox

I'm printing a filled form PDF with PDFBox and PrinterJob. I can create and print just fine but with the PrinterJob I cannot seem to follow the progress or even check if it is finished or not.

I have found that I can count the queued printerjobs but without a name/id I cannot link them to the pdf I'm printing.

I would like to know if there is a way to either check the progress or at least know if a specific (named) PrinterJob is finished.

```
public void print(PDDocument document, String printerName, boolean silentPrint) throws Exception
{
    PrintService printService = getPrinter(printerName);
    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    printJob.setPrintService(printService);
    PDFPrintable pageable = new PDFPrintable(document,Scaling.ACTUAL_SIZE);
    PageFormat format = printJob.defaultPage();
    format.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);

    printJob.setPrintable(pageable, format);
    printJob.print();
}

private static PrintService getPrinter(String printerName) throws Exception
{

    PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
    PrintService myPrinter = null;
    if(services.length == 0)
        throw new Exception("Cannot find printer");
    for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++)
    {
        String svcName = services[i].toString();  
        System.out.println("service found: "+svcName);
        if (svcName.contains(printerName))
        {
            myPrinter = services[i];
            System.out.println("my printer found: "+svcName);
            break;
        }
    }
    return myPrinter;
}

public static int getPrinterJobCount(String printerName) throws Exception
{
    PrintService service = getPrinter(printerName);
    Attribute[] attrs = service.getAttributes().toArray();

    for (int j=0; j<attrs.length; j++) {

        // Get the name of the category of which this attribute value is an instance. 
        String attrName = attrs[j].getName();
        // get the attribute value
        String attrValue = attrs[j].toString();

        if(attrName.equals("queued-job-count"))
            return Integer.parseInt(attrValue);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Its been such a long time I cannot remember and no longer have access to the code base I was working on at the time. Sorry..